# Android GridLayout fit for all size

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I'm porting an iOS app on Android but can't fit this simple layout for all sizes:

The problem is that `ImageButton`s don't scale.
This layout fit like a glove only with Nexus 4

I put images in `drawable-mdpi`

`GridLayout` must be a table with a `WebView` that span 3 columns on the top and 3x3 button images

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:scaleType="center"
android:useDefaultMargins="true" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/userWebView"

    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_columnSpan="3"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:layout_row="0" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:background="@drawable/box_1"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:background="@drawable/box_2"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="3"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:background="@drawable/box_3"
    android:scaleType="center" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn4"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
    android:layout_row="3"
    android:layout_rowSpan="2"
    android:background="@drawable/box_4"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn5"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_row="4"
    android:background="@drawable/box_5"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_column="3"
    android:layout_row="4"
    android:background="@drawable/box_6"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn7"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
    android:layout_row="6"
    android:layout_rowSpan="2"
    android:background="@drawable/box_7"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn8"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
    android:layout_row="7"
    android:background="@drawable/box_8"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn9"
    android:layout_column="3"
    android:layout_row="7"
    android:background="@drawable/box_9"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't put your images just in `drawable-mdpi`, also put the convenient ones to other co-drawable folders like `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-xhdpi` etc. Or just create a new folder named `drawable`, no prefix or suffix, and put your images into it

Comment: the problem is that different device with different resolution are for example xhdpi .... i simply want that image button resize for the current screen. On nexus 4 3x3 button ( 120px each image ) fit perfect :\

Comment: ok empty all of your drawable folders, and create a one just named drawable, no preffix or suffix, and put your image assets into it, if avaiable make your images 9-patch so they will fit perfect on all devices,

Comment: can you post the screenshots for the devices you have tested so far?

Comment: as you can see in nexus s button 3, 6 and 9 was cutted, in nexus 4 all fit perfect.

Comment: make your grid_view width fill_parent

Comment: hımm weird; try to make your column_count auto

Comment: nothing. If i create drawable-normal drawable-xlarge i can put images for different screen but doesn't fit for all devices. Maybe  should i change layout type?

Comment: remoev scaleType attribute from your gridlayout, and put android:scaleType="fitCenter" on all of your imagebuttons

Comment: On emulator is always the same :\

Comment: try it on real device